# JQuery plugin for image annotations?

Tags: jquery-plugins

We're working on a project that requires us to display an image and allow a user to click on various spots on the image and add text annotations (think Facebook photo tagging).  We also want to be able to rotate and zoom the image.

Has anyone worked with any JQuery plug-ins that provide this type of functionaty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar requirement and I found these plugins to solve it.

1. [ZURB](http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascript-annotation-plugin)
2. [Flicker like annotation](http://flipbit.co.uk/jquery-image-annotation.html)
3. [Another modified version](http://mystuff.berense.org/posts/2010-11/my-stuff-image-annotations)

Answer (score 2):

Nice jQuery plugin for adding annotation.

http://codecanyon.net/item/adddot-the-jquery-plugin-for-adding-hot-spots/1860111

Comment: Not open source, though OP haven't specified so.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery plugin for image annotations, but without zooming http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/