# Jquery plugin to show annotations on page with handwritten arrow (Like EnjoyHint without the tour part)

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to show "annotations" in a page to hint users. The annotations will be always on (No tooltip effect is necessary).

Examples:
[image]
[image]

**Do you know a jQuery plugin/javascript project to do so?**

Bonus point if the arrow is created on the fly with SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [d3-annotation plug in](http://d3-annotation.susielu.com/). Kind of too heavy, but it gets the work done

[image]

Answer (score 2):

EnjoyHint JS plugin can help you to solve the problem! 
.
see on github [EnjoyHint](https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint)

to know more about click [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/hints-creation-with-enjoyhint/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a librairies suggested here : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728384/jquery-plugin-for-image-annotations)? It would be quite easy to apply css to make it look like you want for the text part.

As for the arrows, you could use [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) (that is not a jQuery plugin but it is a nice tool to work with vectorial content)

Comment: Before start building my own solution will wait if there is any project already done

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/12/annotation-overlay-effect/), looks like what you are looking for. [DEMO here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnnotationOverlayEffect/)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. The overlay is another image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: [intro.js](https://introjs.com/)

It works with tutorial steps and also with individual hints, that even can be loaded by JSON requests.

Plus, as the documentation says, "works very well with all types of elements on the page, including SVG. All you need to do is adding the attributes to SVG elements".